# Socket streaming in java using eclipse for windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, sockets

I'm working on a project to simulate skype app through lan which requires socket implementation if I'm to use java. There is no particular information available in the web on how to work on this subject. Any valuable tips are welcomed or suggestions are entertained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, is there any specific point you're stuck with?
I believe Skype is closed source and I wouldn't expect there to be too much easily accessible information on it's inner workings.
On the other hand I think you should be able to interface with a local Skype installation as I believe that there is a documented interface for that.

Comment: I am yet to start with the coding part of the project. I need something concrete to work with. And I haven't come across any such documentations.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely seen this, but Oracle provides some pretty in-depth documentation on sockets in [Lesson: All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

In this series of lessons, you're shown how to read from and write to sockets in Java, thus sending data to and receiving data from the computer you're connected to. Perhaps you could start with something simple like sending audio files over LAN, then see if you can actively write audio to the socket which could then be read and played on the receiving machine.

**EDIT**: Good 'ol Bucky has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr02nyPqLBU) on building an IM program using sockets in Java which should put you at a starting point for your mock-Skype application.

*Best of luck!*

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'll surely work on this lead.